# Create Data Dependent Dynamic Excel Drop down

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula, excel-2007

I want to create a excel drop-down without using VBA. Fields available in column A gets "0" or "1" depending on some other logic.Values in Column B are static.I want to create a drop-down which will show the values from column B if the values in the corresponding row(in column A) is 1. I tried using OFFSET and COUNTIF but unsuccessful.

[image: Please check the attachment]

Answer (score 0):

Insert a table.  Select the range of your data, and then use the dropdowns in the table to filter your results.

[image: Table]
[image: Result1]
[image: Result2]
[image: Result3]